# Retrieving remote file with Webistrano

Tags: capistrano, webistrano

I'm wanting to have a task that will be able to bundle up some remote files and allow the Webistrano user download these files to their machine.

Capistrano has the [DSL Download/Get](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-File-Transfer-Download) which will perform an sftp or scp transfer. This works with webistrano, but only downloads it to the Webistrano server.

What can I do from this point to serve this file back to the User?